# jQuery loop array with div content inside with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array called `listArray()` which contains two properties `pageNumber` and `content`.

The property `content` holds the container div html. This is useful because I have a pagination and I don't save that info into the database in real time, instead I insert into an array and only in the end is when I insert into the database.

```
$container = $('#container');

$.each(listArray, function(index, value){

    // So, for each index in array
    // it must empty the container
    // to receive a new value
    $container.empty();
    $container.append(value.content); // value.content = pure html      

    html2canvas($container, {
        height: $container.height() + 180,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');           
            var file = dataURLtoBlob(data);

            var formObjects = new FormData();
            formObjects.append('file', file);

            $.ajax({
               url: 'ajax_saveImage',
               type: 'POST',
               data: formObjects,
               processData: false,
               contentType: false,
            });
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see my final goal is to save two or three or even more images. My problem is that all the images are being saved BUT with the last index (of the array) content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**.

The solution was not loop, but instead call the function the amount of times needed. The solution came  to my mind after looking at this topic [Looping html2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275799/looping-html2canvas)

```
var i = 0;

function saveIt(){  
    $container.empty();

    if(i <= listArray.length - 1){

        $container.append(listArray[i]['content']);

        html2canvas($container, {
            height: $container.height() + 180,
            letterRendering: true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {

                var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');           
                var file = dataURLtoBlob(data);

                var formObjects = new FormData();
                formObjects.append('file', file);

                $.ajax({
                   url: 'ajax_saveImage',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: formObjects,
                   processData: false,
                   contentType: false,
                });

                i++;
                saveIt(); // Important! - call the function again
            }
        });
    }
}
```